# Excel Dynamic sumproduct

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have created a vector (range of values) of the form (a_11,..,a_1n,...,a_m1...,a_mn) for m and n which are input from another sheet and a vector of probabilities (p_1,...,p_n). In another sheet I now have different subsets of 1,..,m as input so for example I have the string "1,3,4". I would now like to calculate for this string

a_11*a_31*a_41*p_1+a_12*a_32*a_42*p_2+...+a_1n* a_3n* a_4n*p_n 
(basically the sumproduct of the vectors (a_11,...,a_1n), (a_31,...,a_3n), (a_41,...,a_4n) and (p_1,...,p_n)

As the string "1,3,4" differs each time (also in length) I would like to do this dynamically but without using VBA. I have already succeeded doing it in VBA by means of a double loop but I want to use the solver so I want to implement it in a sheet refering to the entries.

Could anyone please help me?

Comment: Can't you do it with matrix formulas?

Comment: For the string "1,3,4" this would require 2 matrix multiplications but the string length can differ. Personally I wouldnt know how to do this in a worksheet without using VBA. Any suggestions?

Comment: How about if your m x n matrix becomes an (m+1) x n matrix A = {a_11, .. ,a_1n;1, .. ,1;a_31, .. , a_3n; a_41, .. , a_4n; 1, .. , 1; .. ; 1, .. , 1; p_1, .. p_n}? Then, a static formula in products and sums will work. To do this, instead of simply "1,3,4", you need a matrix of (m+1) x 1 B = {1;0;1;1;0;  .. ;0;1}, the formula of the products of column 1 e.g. becomes a_1n^b_11 * a_21^b_21 * .. * a_mn^b_m1 * p_1^b_(m+1)1, where b_m1 is an element in B